# Data Interface for Async access

Tags: c#, asynchronous

My standard layout for any data access involves a nice simple interface.

```
    public interface IUserDao
    {
      User GetUser(int userId);
    }
```

I can then switch in a different implementation of the data layer for unit testing.  A standard use would be from a presenter in MVP to do something simple like pushing the data into view.

```
    public void UserSelected(int userId)
    {
       User user = daoFactory.UserDao.GetUser(userId);

       view.FirstName = user.FirstName;
       view.LastName = user.LastName;
    }
```

In this instance the data access needs to be completed asynchronously.  I can't quite get my head around if the requirement for async call should make its way down as far as the data interface.

e.g.

```
    public interface IUserDao
    {
      void GetUserBegin(int userId);
      User GetUserEnd();
    }
```

Do I need to alter the interface or is the requirement of async access just part of the implementation in the calling code?

**EDIT :**

I thought my simple example would help but it may actually be causing some confusion. I am using RestSharp to obtain the data I need and that nicely handles the async part for me.  What I can't work out is how I can wrap an interface around this lot so I can switch it out during testing.

```
public UserDao : IUserDao
{
    public void GetUser(int userId)
    {           
        var request = new RestRequest("User/GetUser/{id}", Method.POST);

        // replaces matching token in request.Resource
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", id.ToString()); 

        //Create the client
        var client = AuthenticatedRestClient();

        //Execute
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            ProcessUser(response);
        });
    }        

    public static void ProcessUser(IRestResponse response)
    {
        //Extract the user from the reponse
        User user = (User)ProcessResponse<User>(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the latest version of .NET, you can take advantage of [`async - await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx):

```
public interface IUserDao
{
    Task<User> GetUser(int userId);
}

public async Task UserSelected(int userId)
{
   User user = await daoFactory.UserDao.GetUser(userId);

   view.FirstName = user.FirstName;
   view.LastName = user.LastName;
}
```

Please note that the implementation of `GetUser` should return `Task<User>`.

If you are on version .NET 4.0, you can use `Task` to call  `UserSelected` from upper method:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UserSelected(userId));
```

Comment: Many thanks. If I weren't using the latest version of .Net how would I approach this.  I am working on a project using Xamarin and async for iOS and Android is only in preview. http://blog.xamarin.com/brave-new-async-mobile-world/

Answer (score 4):

If your using the await pattern you can just do

```
public interface IUserDao
{
  Task<User> GetUser(int userId);
}
```

and to call it

```
 User user = await daoFactory.UserDao.GetUser(userId);
```

Its nice because it informs your application layer that this method was made to be called asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

.Net has three patterns for asynchronous operations:

- [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx)
- [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)
- [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)

For your case I would prefer Task.